# Scrapy crawler not crawling or can't write to csv file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

Project: https://github.com/smalik/resume_scraper

I run this bot using the command:

```
sudo scrapy crawl indeed_resume -o items.csv
```

Problem is that it is either not crawling properly (0 pages) or is unable to write the csv file for some reason. Is it possible that the error is due to depreciated modules? Here is the terminal output when it runs:

```
/home/shap/Desktop/resume_crawlers/resume_scraper-master/resume_data/spiders/resume_indeed.py:10: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.contrib.spiders` is deprecated, use `scrapy.spiders` instead
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
/home/shap/Desktop/resume_crawlers/resume_scraper-master/resume_data/spiders/resume_indeed.py:11: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.contrib.linkextractors` is deprecated, use `scrapy.linkextractors` instead
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
/home/shap/Desktop/resume_crawlers/resume_scraper-master/resume_data/spiders/resume_indeed.py:11: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml` is deprecated, use `scrapy.linkextractors.sgml` instead
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
/home/shap/Desktop/resume_crawlers/resume_scraper-master/resume_data/spiders/resume_indeed.py:33: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: SgmlLinkExtractor is deprecated and will be removed in future releases. Please use scrapy.linkextractors.LinkExtractor
rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths = ('//a[@class="instl confirm-nav next"]')), callback = "parse_item", follow = True),)
2017-01-09 14:39:22 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.0 started (bot: resume_data)
2017-01-09 14:39:22 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'resume_data.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'items.csv', 'DEPTH_LIMIT': 50, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['resume_data.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'resume_data', 'AJAXCRAWL_ENABLED': True, 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False, 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'MEMUSAGE_REPORT': True, 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 2}
2017-01-09 14:39:22 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-01-09 14:39:22 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.ajaxcrawl.AjaxCrawlMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-01-09 14:39:22 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-01-09 14:39:22 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-01-09 14:39:22 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-01-09 14:39:22 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-01-09 14:39:22 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-01-09 14:39:22 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (307) to <GET https://www.indeed.com/resumes/mechanical-engineer> from <GET http://www.indeed.com/resumes/mechanical-engineer>
2017-01-09 14:39:24 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (307) to <GET https://www.indeed.com/resumes/mechanical-engineering> from <GET http://www.indeed.com/resumes/mechanical-engineering>
2017-01-09 14:39:26 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (307) to <GET https://www.indeed.com/resumes/piping-engineer> from <GET http://www.indeed.com/resumes/piping-engineer>
2017-01-09 14:39:28 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (307) to <GET https://www.indeed.com/resumes/java> from <GET http://www.indeed.com/resumes/java>
2017-01-09 14:39:30 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (307) to <GET https://www.indeed.com/resumes/SAS> from <GET http://www.indeed.com/resumes/SAS>
2017-01-09 14:39:32 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (307) to <GET https://www.indeed.com/resumes/javascript> from <GET http://www.indeed.com/resumes/javascript>
2017-01-09 14:39:35 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (307) to <GET https://www.indeed.com/resumes/marketing-analyst> from <GET http://www.indeed.com/resumes/marketing-analyst>
2017-01-09 14:39:40 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.indeed.com/resumes/mechanical-engineering> (referer: None)
2017-01-09 14:39:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.indeed.com/resumes/piping-engineer> (referer: None)
2017-01-09 14:39:45 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.indeed.com/resumes/java> (referer: None)
2017-01-09 14:39:47 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.indeed.com/resumes/SAS> (referer: None)
2017-01-09 14:39:49 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.indeed.com/resumes/javascript> (referer: None)
2017-01-09 14:39:52 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.indeed.com/resumes/marketing-analyst> (referer: None)
2017-01-09 14:40:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.indeed.com/resumes/mechanical-engineer> (referer: None)
2017-01-09 14:40:00 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-01-09 14:40:00 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 3260,
'downloader/request_count': 14,
'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 14,
'downloader/response_bytes': 127215,
'downloader/response_count': 14,
'downloader/response_status_count/200': 7,
'downloader/response_status_count/307': 7,
'finish_reason': 'finished',
'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 9, 22, 40, 0, 662954),
'log_count/DEBUG': 15,
'log_count/INFO': 7,
'response_received_count': 7,
'scheduler/dequeued': 14,
'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 14,
'scheduler/enqueued': 14,
'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 14,
'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 9, 22, 39, 22, 288258)}
2017-01-09 14:40:00 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spider doesn't seem to crawl anything other than urls defined in `start_urls`.

The issue in your code is that your `Rules` and `Linkextractors` are not extracting anything.
A good way to test your linkextractors is to use `scrapy shell`:

```
$ scrapy shell "https://www.indeed.com/resumes/javascript"
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
le = LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//a[contains(@class,"app_link")]')
le.extract_links(response)
#< returns 50 scrapy.link.Link objects here>
```

The example above contains correct xpath for capturing urls to job offers. You can use this approach to fix your spider.

Comment: Followed your procedure and it seems that `Linkextractors` does in fact work. Will try using it to fix the spider now

Comment: @user3787179 the one in my example does, but the one in your code doesn't, this one to be more exact: https://github.com/smalik/resume_scraper/blob/master/resume_data/spiders/resume_indeed.py#L33

Comment: Sorry I got confused there for a second, thanks. It works.

Comment: So the spider crawls the pages but does not scrap any info. I am assuming this is because they changed their interface and all the links in the spider (not my original work) are out of date. Could I ask you how you found the correct link so i can go through that process with all the other links?

Comment: @user3787179 the subject is a bit to broad to explain in a stackoverflow comment. But to generalise it - it's all about `xpath`, you can use tools included with your browser to inspect the html tree and design an intruction piece that tells scrapy how to reach the data you need. w3school intro would be a good start: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

Comment: I looking for the elements using firefox, no problem finding all the content in the resume but not 'app_link' maybe i'm just being an idiot, haven played with html in a while

Comment: @user3787179 Here's a screenshot(sorry for unusual dark theme): http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/5320/BDjVJo.png that on firefox with firebug by right clicking link and selecting "inspect element with firebug", though it should be pretty much the same on other browsers/tools.